# scala: How to convert an anonymous function to val

Tags: scala

I'm a beginner learning scala and looking into anon functions and vals.
I'm not able to convert `{case e if e % 2 == 0 => e}` to a Val. I've tried different syntax (sample shown below) to no avail. There is no real purpose for converting to val; just trying to get a deeper understanding.

```
package exercises.functions

object CollectVal extends App {
  println(List(1,2,3,4,5).collect{case e if e % 2 == 0 => e})
  //  val onlyEvens: Int = e:Int => Int = e if (e % 2 == 0 ) =>  e
  //  val onlyEvens = e:Int = {case e if e % 2 == 0 => e}
  println(List(1,2,3,4,5).collect{onlyEvens})
}
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax to assign an anonymous function to a `val` would be something like this (note parentheses around `e`):

```
   val x: Int => Int = (e) => if (e % 2 == 0) e else ???
```

or equivalently, but a bit shorter: `val x = (e: Int) => if (e % 2 == 0) e else ???`

But it looks like what you are looking for is a *partial function* rather than just a function. `PartialFunction` is like a regular function, but it is only defined for some of the possible values of its parameter. In your case, you want it only defined for even numbers:

```
    val x = PartialFunction[Int, Int] { case e if e % 2 == 0 => e }
```

The `{ case foo => bar }` shorthand works for partial functions but not regular functions, that's why you were having problems trying to define a function that way. This creates a `PartialFunction` that is defined for all integer values that match one of the `case` clauses, and not for any others.

Comment: "The { case foo => bar } shorthand works for partial functions but not regular functions" I am not sure what you mean here; `val x: Int => Int = { case e if e % 2 == 0 => e }` works fine.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to express is a function. So the type of the variable in this case is:

```
val onlyEvens: Int => Int
```

In particular, collect accept a `PartialFunction` (i.e. a function that is not defined for some input value). So it is more correct to write:

```
val onlyEvens: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case e if e % 2 == 0 => e }
```

Finally, you can pass this val in the collect method:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).collect(onlyEvens)
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cric96/pMymbyIgQMSKr163jYX0vg/66)